# React and Emotion (css) : styling cells in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emotion

I'm somewhat new to React, so bear with me.
I need to style all cells of a table element. In plain css it would look something like this:

```
table.mailTable {
  border : 1px solid grey;
}
```

But how would I accompish that with Emotion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying something like this.

```
<table
    className={css`
      padding: 32px;
      background-color: hotpink;
      font-size: 24px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      &table.mailTable {
  border : 1px solid grey;
}
    `}
  >
    Hover to change color.
  </table>
```

Comment: Will that target table cells ?

Comment: You need to modify the above code according to your need. if you are targeting all the cells, you can use table.td or table.tr. depending on your need.